# Is it necessary to use StateNotifier even if there is only one value and no method?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-change-notifier, flutter-riverpod

If there is only one value and no method, do we still need to use StateNotifier as follows? Or is there a simpler mechanism?

Since this value is rewritten and referenced from the outside, the corresponding function must be included in the ChangeNotifier's notifyListeners();.

```
class BoolNotifier extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  BoolNotifier() : super(false);
}

final isA = StateNotifierProvider<BoolNotifier, bool>(
  (ref) => BoolNotifier(),
);

final isB = StateNotifierProvider<BoolNotifier, bool>(
  (ref) => BoolNotifier(),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `StateProvider`:

```dart
final boolProvider = StateProvider<bool>((ref) => true);

final isA = Provider<bool>(
  (ref) => ref.watch(boolProvider),
);

final isB = Provider<bool>(
  (ref) => ref.watch(boolProvider),
);
```

You can change the state like this:

```dart
ref.read(boolProvider.notifier).update((state) => !state);
// or so
ref.read(boolProvider.notifier).state = newValue;
```